# WPF InkCanvas Z-Index for strokes

Tags: wpf, inkcanvas

In WPF InkCanvas, ink is rendered on top and strokes don't have z-index property. I have other UIElements like shape, images on InkCanvas and can't bring UIElements to top. Is there any work around for this problem. I have tried
below things.

1) use two different InkCanvas (one for strokes & one for UIElements)
- Can't achieve sandwich effect in this (i.e. UIElement between strokes
[Something like this in this circle is UIElement](https://i.stack.imgur.com/75Xuh.jpg)
2) Masking strokes using geometry path and add as UIElement 
- If I add strokes as UIElements (using path) then I will loose erase functionality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The map editor which is part of our game suite uses ink to draw terrain so I have recent experience of this sort of thing.

The way my app works is you select a thing you're drawing ( woods, road, contour etc ) and draw a stroke using ink.

I then process that stroke and obtain a geometry.
I pass that to a viewmodel > itemssource > itemscontrol.
This is then templated into a piece of terrain.
This itemscontrol is below the inkcanvas.
The user can manipulate the z-index of those by moving them up and down in the observablecollection.
I rely on just the order to define z-index.

I also retain the data from each stroke by serialising it.

You're thinking "how about erase?".
To do that I'd have an explicit erase-this-thing mode.
Let them pick a shape and get it's stroke data, add the stroke back to the inkcanvas. Once they finish erasing then use a "save changes" button or something to re-process the stroke(s) and switch back to edit mode.

Since this is a game map editor I'm working on, drawing produces area and line types of terrain but their area/line is defined by a geometry translated from a stroke.  ZIndex corresponds to the order of objects in the left panel. The buttons you can see with the chevrons pointing up and down move the order of a 
[image]

Comment: I appreciate your help. But again sandwich effect (strokes-UIElements-strokes) can't be achieved using your solution. I have attached image for your reference In original question.

Comment: Yes it can. The itemscontrol in my app has a canvas for it's itemspanel. Geometries are used to template into objects on that. The zindex is defined by the order I add the viewmodels. The red one would be first, then yellow then black, then blue.  They would overlay each other like your picture. I also have a mechanism to re-order the viewmodels to change that zindex..